# Moving annotations in MKMapView according to server data (latitude and longitude)

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

In my app I am showing location of some other person by getting their location (latitude and longitude) from server at particular interval.

After getting I have to remove all annotations and drop new annotations based on the server data.

But it looks very inefficient as when we have the annotation for the same user previously exists even then I'm removing and adding the same user annotation.

So I want to know can we move the MKAnnotation from one coordinate to other? I have tried "setCoordinate" property but unable to succesfuly implement it.

Also it is not "touch and drag" kind. The annotations move itself when the app get data (latitude and longitude) from server.

Comment: Please explain in detail why setCoordinate didn't work (compiler error, warning, run-time error and crash, other).  Show the annotation class .h and .m.  Don't understand what you mean by the last paragraph ("not touch and drag kind...").

Comment: Actually i dont know how to access MKAnnotation objects in MKMapView (anywhere other than "viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation")..I tried ....NSArray *pinGreen = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.mapView annotations]];
 for(int i = 0 ; i< [pinGreen count]; i++){
  if([[pinGreen objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[MapViewAnnotation class]])
  {
   
   [self.mapView removeAnnotation:[pinGreen objectAtIndex:i]];
  
   
  }
  
  
 }......But this gives "MapViewAnnotation" kind object not "MKAnnotation" and to setCoordinate it is require as [someAnnotation setCoordinate:cordinate]

Comment: Your conclusion that it is "impossible" is incorrect.  Of course you can move annotation views either directly or indirectly using setCoordinate on the annotation.

Comment: Ok.then wil you please tell me how it is done using only MKAnnotation,MKPinAnnotationView and MapViewAnnotation and their delegate methods.It would be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is that a performance problem? Have you mesaured it?
You're just changing an array of objects, not even creating new instances.

The AnnotationViews on the `MapView` will be reused anyway. There shouldn't be any problems with that.

Comment: Yes.you are right they are reused.But it is better to move the pin as location changes then to remove and redraw (actually its my client requirement). So i want to move them instead of remove and redraw for same user.

Comment: ok..thanks...it means it is impossible to move on their own the MKAnnotation views

Answer (score 3):

To change an annotation's coordinate without removing, re-creating and adding it again, create an annotation class where the `coordinate` property is settable.  A simple way to do this is to define the `coordinate` property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

Alternatively, instead of defining your own class, you could also use the built-in `MKPointAnnotation` class which has a settable `coordinate`.

You initially create and add the annotations as usual.  For example:

```
MKPointAnnotation *pa = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
pa.coordinate = someCoordinate;
pa.title = @"User1";
[mapView addAnnotation:pa];
[pa release];
```

Later, when you get an update from the server and the coordinates for "User1" change, you can either search for that user's annotation in the map view's `annotations` array or store the references to the annotations in some other structure that allows quick access using a key like an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Once you have found the annotation, you just set the annotation's `coordinate` property to the new value and the map view will automatically move the annotation's view to the new location.

This example searches the `annotations` array:

```
for (id<MKAnnotation> ann in mapView.annotations)
{
    if ([ann.title isEqualToString:@"User1"])
    {
        ann.coordinate = theNewCoordinate;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you want to find the annotation using a different, custom property of your annotation class (say some int named userIdNumber):

```
for (id<MKAnnotation> ann in mapView.annotations)
{
    if ([ann isKindOfClass:[YourAnnotationClass class]])
    {
        YourAnnotationClass *yacAnn = (YourAnnotationClass *)ann;
        if (yacAnn.userIdNumber == user1Id)
        {
            yacAnn.coordinate = theNewCoordinate;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The above is just an example of how to change the coordinate.  If you have lots of annotations with changing coordinates, I don't recommend searching for them one-at-a-time.  Instead, you could store the references in a dictionary and look them up quickly using a key value.