# Moving annotation from one coordinate point to another in Swift

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

This is a repost. I tried all I could do to get this thing done but wasn't successful. 
I have two coordinate points and all I'm trying to do is moving an annotation from one point to another.

As an alternative solution, I found an Obj-C project in [github](https://github.com/100grams/Moving-MKAnnotationView) which is very similar to this and I made a bridged connection between Swift and Obj-C to get this done. But for just moving annotation I had to use this whole project which I found is not a good solution.

Anyone who was successful in implementing such functionality (in swift)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `MKPointAnnotation` as base, you can access the `coordinate` property, which is actually defined as `var`, e.g.

```
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

[Apple MKPointAnnotation Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPointAnnotation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKPointAnnotation/coordinate). Therefore, when changing the coordinate, your annotation will move to another location.

Comment: But if I change the coordinate then a new annotation will be created right? Like, `ann.coordinate = currLocation2D; mapview.addAnnotation(coordinate)`.I think there's no such method to update the coordinate for the `MKPointAnnotation`.

Comment: No, as far as I'm aware, the coordinate should be relocated once you set that property.

Comment: `mapview.addAnnotation(coordinate)` actually creates new annotaiton right. Could you please post some sample code for my understanding? That might actually help me.

Comment: There is no specific code, just retrieve the annotation and assign the new coordinate to it, e.g. `annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate`. Maybe have a look at [Moving annotations in MKMapView according to server data (latitude and longitude)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563137/moving-annotations-in-mkmapview-according-to-server-data-latitude-and-longitude) (the answer by @Anna)

Comment: How to retrieve annotation from map. map return MKAnnotation not MKpointAnnotation. I have multiple annotation on map. how to retrieve all ?